# Orion-LD Subscription Issues

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am running Orion-LD:0.8.0 as a service in a docker-compose.

I want to create a subscription that fires every time that a new entity of *type=Event* is created in the broker. The subscription should fire the webhook to another service in the docker-compose, which doesn't seem to be working. I'm wondering if it's an issue of how I've written the subscription or something else.

The subscription as returned from the get request in the broker:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Subscription:618397ade7b95210721ae0dd",
        "type": "Subscription",
        "description": "notify of new events",
        "entities": [
            {
                "type": "Event"
            }
        ],
        "notification": {
            "attributes": [
                "id"
            ],
            "format": "keyValues",
            "endpoint": {
                "uri": "http://anotherservice:1234/hook/events",
                "accept": "application/json"
            }
        },
        "@context": "linktocontext"
    }
]
```

Comment: Had you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem to yours. Maybe the problem is that if you use orion-ld, you shold use `"accept": "application/ld+json"` insted of version without `ld`. But I dont think so that is it a case.

Are you using an dockerize version of orion and your app? Try to connect them by docker network. In my case it was smth like that:

```
docker network connect docker_default orion_orion_1
```

Where docker_default depends on `docker-compose.yml` setup.

Other posibility is the way you're posting the subscription info.
My version of doing subscripton to entities is (and it seems to work):

```
subscription_body = {
        "id": subscription_id,
        "description": f"A subscription to get info about entity: entity",
        "type": "Subscription",
        "entities": [{"type": entity_type}],
        "watchedAttributes": attribs,
        "notification": {
            "attributes": attribs,
            "format": "normalized",
            "endpoint": {
                "uri": config['general']['url'],
                "accept": "application/ld+json"
            }
        },
        "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
        "throttling": 0,
        "@context": ["linktocontext"]
    }
    response = requests.post(f"{config['general']['orion-server']}/ngsi-ld/v1/subscriptions",
                             data=json.dumps(subscription_body),
                             headers={'Content-type': 'application/ld+json'})
```

Answer (score 0):

This "type=Event" ...
"Event" will be expanded using the @context "linktocontext".
If you create a new entity with an @context that expands "Event" to something else, the subscription will not trigger any notifications as there is no match.
Perhaps that is the problem?
[ application/json or application/ld+json doesn't matter ]